# Execute statement in PDO inserts blank data inside MySQL

Tags: mysql

I have a problem with execution of a PDO statement. It was working normally yesterday, but today it showed a problem:

The scenario is a user inputs information into a registration form, submits it, and then the server inserts that data inside the database and sends a copy of the information to an email.

Inside the database: The information is blank(except the id field, which auto-increments)
Inside the email: All data is okay
Debug: try/catch, PDOException don't give errors, echo of the data after the execute statement prints the data correctly.

So the problem is, inside the database there are BLANK(not NULL) data in the fields.

```
$stmt = $connect->prepare('INSERT INTO table1 (name, phone, email, gname, ip) VALUES(:name, :phone, :email, :gname, :ip)');
            $stmt->execute(array(
                ':name' => $name,
                ':phone' => $phone,
                ':email' => $email,
                ':gname' => $gname,
                ':ip' => get_user_ip(),
            ));
```

Comment: IIRC, you don't need to have the `:` inside your array keys. You could also replace all of the named parameters, e.g `:name`, `:phone` with question marks (`?`) and remove the keys completely from your execute array. If the code was working previously, and the values are uploaded blank (not null), then I would assume your variables are somehow empty.

Comment: using an echo after the statement returns correct and not blank data somehow, thought. so I am wondering if there is some way to debug what the database gets, because the charset of the table is utf8mb4

Comment: What I would do is create a whole separate variable for your array instead of passing it directly to execute like you are, this way you can `print_r()` exactly what you are passing to your query (usually I would do this right before the `execute()` statement) so you can troubleshoot and verify you are sending what you think you are.

Comment: Thank you for the help, I used that and saw everything is as it should been, I tried adding new data to another database and narrowed it down to a mistake on my behalf when I created a new database, there was nowhere to be initialized the length of the cells, so it took default(0) that caused the problem to insert blank data.

Answer (score 0):

Found my problem, a length of a cell caused to default itself to zero(0) and it imported blank data.